# How can I load some data into Ext.data.Store

Tags: extjs

this is my code

```
        var store = {
            roles_store: new Ext.data.Store({
                        autoLoad: false,
                        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                                                        url: 'a/b/c',
                                                      }),
                        remoteSort: true, 
                        baseParams: {

                                    },
                        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                                                totalProperty: 'total',
                                                root: 'root',
                                                fields:['roles']                
                                                        }),

            })
        };
```

this is my json

{"total":3,"root":[{"roles":"A"},{"roles":"B"},{"roles":"C"}]}

If I wnat to add data into Ext.data.Store. How can I do?

(PS:Sorry,my English is not well. And my extjs is :http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-addSorted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Ext.define('roles', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'roles', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'roles',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'path/to/data/test.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'root',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Check the examples here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

For v3.4:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({

    autoDestroy: true,
    url: 'path/to/data/test.json',
    storeId: 'myStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    idProperty: 'roles',
    root: 'root',
    fields: ['roles'] 
});
```

You need to use the jsonstore:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore

Comment: my extjs is 3-4 : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-addSorted     Is it the same ?